# How can I pass variable in ReadyAPI step using groovy script

Tags: api, groovy, soapui, ready-api

I have a 4 steps in a ReadyAPI only thing changes is step number.

```
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Verify Application1']

def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Verify Application2']

def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Verify Application3']
```

Now, I want to pass a variable instead of 1,2,3 in ReadyAPI step using groovy. So that I can add loop and iterate whenever i need.

Comment: Put the vraiables in a list and iterate the list.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @aman Could you please accept this as an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Run a loop and use concatenation to generated the string you want

```
for(int i=1 ;i<=3 ;i++)
{
   str='Verify Application'
   str=str+i
   log.info str

    def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps[str]

 }
```

output is like

[image]